# How to know if Stripe payment intent or session has been refunded?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

When I iterate through [sessions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list?lang=node) or [payment intents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list?lang=node) using [stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe), status does not reveal if payment has been refunded.

How to know if Stripe payment intent or session has been refunded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PaymentIntent itself will not change when the payment is refunded. In Stripe, refunds are created off of the underlying Charges. You can if a payment intent was refunded by checking its `latest_charge`'s `refunded` property.

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(
  'pi_1234',
  ['expand' => ['latest_charge']]
);
  const refunded = paymentIntent.latest_charge.refunded;
  const amount_refunded = paymentIntent.latest_charge.amount_refunded;
);
```

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors?lang=node#errors-payment_intent-latest_charge

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object?lang=node#charge_object-refunded